# How to divide two dataframes, and replace NaN, inf value with 0 in Pandas Python 3.X

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code:

```
mean= all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].agg('mean').reset_index()

all_data = pd.merge(all_data, mean, suffixes=["", "_mean"], how='left', on=['Id'])
```

Now, I want to add another column to all_data frame, like this:

```
meanDivide = all_data[features] / mean
all_data = pd.merge(all_data, meanDivide, suffixes=["", "_meanDivide"], how='left', on=['Id'])
```

I want to join it on `Id` to all_data. Then replace `Nan` `inf` value with 0 in pandas. I almost spent my whole day on this, but something is still wrong.

Edit: My `all_data` looks something like this:

Id    Row1   Row2
1      6      0
2      5      3
3      2      2
4      0      0
5      3      8

`features` variable, like this:

```
features = ['Row1','Row2']
```

Data in CSV Format:

```
Id,Row1,Row2
1,6,0
2,5,3
3,2,2
4,0,0
5,3,8
```

Comment: Could you please include your sample data so that we can see your desired output?

Comment: @rahlf23 Done bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do not need `merge`

```
newdf=all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].transform('mean')
newdf2=all_data[features]/newdf

pd.concat([all_data,newdf.add_suffix('_mean'),newdf2.add_suffix('_meanDivide')],axis=1)
```

Comment: Hello bro, this works fine but How do I replace `NaN` value with 0? I tried `newdf2.replace([np.inf, np.NINF,np.nan], 0)` but It is not replacing `NaN` value?

Comment: Weird. It replace NaN and inf of `newdf` with 0, but not of `newdf2`.

Comment: @JohnDoe my bad check the update I remove the ' in feature of 2rdline

Comment: Yeah, I noticed and fixed that. What I am asking is that, When I divide in second line. Sometimes, I divide numbers by 0 or something ,and I get NaN or Inf number, how do I replace it with 0? `newdf2.replace([np.inf, np.NINF,np.nan], 0)` is not working for some reasons, I don't know. 
Anyway, your answer is really good, thanks a lot man, seriously appreciate it a lot. Not all heros wear cape

Comment: @JohnDoe newdf2=newdf2.replace([np.inf, np.NINF,np.nan], 0) assign it back